# Testing implementation over interface

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm starting with test coverage for my C++ project and it was oddness for me, that a lot of frameworks cannot create parametrized unit test.

For example I have interface:

```
class IBuffer {
public:
   virtual void pushBytes(void *data, int length) = 0;
   virtual int  getSize() = 0;
};
```

And a few implementors :

```
class BufferImplOne{};
class BufferImplTwo{};
```

Now I want to check that pushing bytes to buffer will really increment its size:

```
TEST_CASE("example/test", "Test for any IBuffer implementor") {

IBuffer *buf = // ... {I want external parameter to be here}

REQUIRE( buf->getSize() == 0 );

int dataLength = 10;
int data[dataLength];
    buf->pushBytes(data, dataLength * sizeof(int));

REQUIRE( buf->getSize() == dataLength * sizeof(int));
}
```

Now I'm gonna to test each implementation, and first thing I want to do - is to check if implementor meets interface tests. But I don't want to copypaste the same code twice, I just want to pass implementation as a parameter to interface test. How to deal with such problem?

I am using [CATCH](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/wiki/Catch-for-Objective-C), but seems like other framework don't provide same functionality too.

Anyway I am newcomer in unit testing and maybe I misunderstood something basic?

Comment: If the implementer doesn't match the interface, you should get a compiler error. You don't need a unit-test to check that. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I add test example. I want to check that pushing new bytes to IBuffer implementor will really increment its size.

Comment: What's the point of name `getSize`? why not just `size`?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
void TestBuffer(IBuffer& buf)
{
    REQUIRE( buf.getSize() == 0 );

    int dataLength = 10;
    int data[dataLength];
    buf.pushBytes(data, dataLength * sizeof(int));

    REQUIRE( buf.getSize() == dataLength * sizeof(int));
}

TEST_CASE("example/test", "Test for BufferImplOne implementor")
{
   BufferImplOne one;
   TestBuffer(one);
}

TEST_CASE("example/test", "Test for BufferImplTwo implementor")
{
   BufferImplTwo two;
   TestBuffer(two);
}
```

Comment: Well, simple enough to be true :) In this case I should create object with few methods where each test one interface aspect. And wrap it to TEST_CASE(...) for given implementation. Looks not bad.

Comment: What is the other way for casting object to interface?

Comment: @LucTouraille to be honest I never use references in such way. What pros on using them instead of pointers?

Comment: @Alex: the main advantage is that a reference can't be NULL, so if passing a NULL value to your function makes no sense, you should enforce that in the interface by taking a reference instead of a pointer. This question has been asked many times on stackoverflow, feel free to browse some of them: [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pointer+reference+inurl%3Astackoverflow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&hl=en).

Comment: @MatthieuM: Initially I did use a reference, but before submitting the answer I changed it to a pointer to match the code in the original question because I didn't want to get into other concepts. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's bona fide polymorphism.

```
void test(IBuffer& ib) {
    // ... your tests here ...
}

int main() {
    BufferImplOne one;
    test(one);

    BufferImplTwo two;
    test(two);
}
```

I don't quite see what a framework could provide...